# I'm getting error Method not found: 'Void System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(!!0, IntPtr, Boolean)'

Tags: c#

I have installed Visual studio 2010, dotnetframework 4.0 and SAP CrystalReport 13.

But I run website on IIS :

> Server Error in '/' Application. Method not found: 'Void
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(!!0, IntPtr,
> Boolean)'. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
> execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
> for more information about the error and where it originated in the
> code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
> 'Void System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(!!0,
> IntPtr, Boolean)'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(!!0, IntPtr,
> Boolean)'.]
> CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.DataSetConverter.Wrap(Object
> dataset, CrdbAdoPlusDelegate& adoPlusDelegate) +0
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.WrapAndCacheDotNetObject(Object
> val, Type type, ISCRAdoNetDataSet& crAdoNetDataSet) +240
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.SetDataSource(Object val,
> Type type) +344
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object
> val, Type type) +142
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataTable
> dataTable) +66    ReportView.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> +46720    System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
> System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
> EventArgs e) +35    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +2207

pls help me ! thanks.

Comment: Not that its likely your problem, but why are you using such outdated software and frameworks ?

Comment: `Marshal.StructureToPtr` is in the Framework since .Net 4.5.1. Which makes the previous comment more relevant. Time to update.

Comment: Because my company using this program, i cant iupdate

Comment: You don't need to update Crystal Reports, but you do need to update your .NET framework, as the problem is exactly that CP is calling methods that aren't present in the current version of the framework. Update to [the most recent 4.x version your system supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements#supported-server-operating-systems), even very old systems support more recent things than 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade .net to 4.5.2 or newer